# Why can't Albacore find msbuild?

Tags: ruby, msbuild, rake, albacore

My rake build throws the following exception:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `msbuild'

Task is:

```
 msbuild :framework do |msb|   
    msb.solution = "pathToMySln"  
    msb.verbosity = 'minimal' 
 end
```

I have the following gems installed:

- albacore (0.3.4)
- bundler (1.3.5)
- nokogiri (1.5.5 x86-mingw32)
- rake (0.9.2.2)
- rubyzip (0.9.9)

How can I fix that error?

Comment: Could you add your entire file where you are defining your task?

Comment: There are several major releases of Albacore available, 1.0 (which contains the same `msbuild` method) and 2.0 (which has a new cross-platform `build` task). https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/wiki/build

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for response. I got the list of gems running

> bundle exec gem list

but I have figured out that I had newer versions of rake and albacore installed on my machine. I have uninstalled newer gems and it works